# How do I get the content of the Entity object from the HttpResponse instance?

Tags: java, maven, httpclient

I get an error everytime I try to get the content of an Entity object.

```
package com.mycompany.prueba_rest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpResponse;

public class Prueba_REST {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
       // Crear objeto HttpClient.
       CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

       //Crear un objeto HttpGet.
       HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.tutorialspoint.com");

       //Imprimir por pantalla el método usado.
       System.out.println("Request Type: "+httpget.getMethod());

       //Ejecutar el pedido GET.
       HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);

                                                  // Error here!
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(httpresponse.getEntity().getContent());
    }
}
```

I tried changing the version of the repository and looking for information in the official documentation that could help me solve this problem.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code instead of using a screenshot. Please also include what the error message is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`getEntity()`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/classic/CloseableHttpResponse.html#getEntity--) method belongs to [`CloseableHttpResponse`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/classic/CloseableHttpResponse.html), not [`HttpResponse`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.1.x/current/httpcore5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/core5/http/HttpResponse.html). Just change your code to use the former:

```
CloseableHttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(httpresponse.getEntity().getContent());
```

Be aware that [`CloseableHttpClient#execute(ClassicHttpRequest)`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/classic/CloseableHttpClient.html#execute-org.apache.hc.core5.http.ClassicHttpRequest-) is deprecated. You should instead use an execute with an [`HttpClientResponseHandler`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.2.x/current/httpcore5/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/hc/core5/http/io/HttpClientResponseHandler.html), which will automatically deallocate any resources. Here's an example:

```
MyObject myObject = httpclient.execute(httpget, new HttpClientResponseHandler<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public MyObject handleResponse(ClassicHttpResponse response) throws HttpException, IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(response.getEntity().getContent());
        int id = scanner.nextInt();
        String name = scanner.next();
        String description = scanner.nextLine();
        return new MyObject(id, name, description);
    }
});
```